# Martingale and submartingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

When $X_n$ is a martingale we know $(X_n)^+$, i.e. the positive part of $X_n$, is also a submartingale.
Is this true? It is easy to show that this is SUB-m.g. but I couldn't find a counter-example for martingale?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most certainly false.

The function $x \longmapsto x^+$ is convex so if $X_n$ is a martingale then $X_ n^+$ is a submartingale, and will not be a martingale unless $X_n \geq 0$ a.s. for all $n$ or $X_n \leq 0$ a.s. for all $n$.

Here we have used the conditional version of Jensen's inequality to show that for a convex function $\phi$
$$
E_n[\phi(X_{n+1})] \geq \phi(E_n[X_{n+1}]) = \phi(X_n)
$$
almost surely (this is the submartingale property for the new process $\{\phi(X_n)\}_n$.

For an explicit example consider a symmetric random walk with $X_0 = 0$. Clearly $E[X_n^+]>0$ as $X_n^+$ is not a.s. zero, so the process $\{X_n^+\}_n$ cannot be a martingale as this would imply $E[X_n^+]=0$ for all $n$ (martingales have constant expectation).

Comment: can you make it more explicit say you got 2 turns then E[X_2^+|X_1] > X_1^+ How to show this in this symmetric random walk? Thank you!

Comment: When we say $X_n$ is a martingale, implicitly we keep in the back of our minds that we mean $(X_n,\mathcal{F}_n)$ is a martingale on the filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}_n\}_n,P)$. I am using $E_n[\cdot]$ as shorthand for $E[\cdot | \mathcal{F}_n]$, **not** $E[\cdot | X_n]$.

Comment: Showing $\{X_n\}_n$ is a submartingale is literally just plugging in $(x \longmapsto x^+)$ for $\phi$ in the inequality above.